# Better way to control granularity of splitting string by word/token or character

Tags: python, string, split, nlp, token

I've a common operations that either allows user to use "word" or "char" as unit and I've been doing it as such:

```
def split(s, unit):
    return s.split() if unit == 'word' else list(s)
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> foo = "this is a foo bar sentence"
>>> split(foo, 'word')
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence']
>>> split(foo, 'char')
['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r', ' ', 's', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e']
```

**Is there a simple/better way to create a function that splits the input strings according to words (defined by `str.split`) and by characters?**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do. I'll assume you want a function that splits the input into words if it has multiple words and into characters otherwise:

```py
def split(s):
    l = s.split()
    return l if len(l) > 1 else list(s)
```

Let me know if you had something else in mind.